# How to edit gridview button size but not the input textbox as well

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to figure out a way to edit the command column gridview buttons so that they are equal in size. I am using a CssClass for the gridivew and it is shown below:

```
.gvbutton input {
 width: 79px;
 height: 28px;
```

}

The problem that I am running into is that while this regulates my command column buttons to be equal in size it also regulates the edit textbox to only allow text 79px long instead of the length of the textbox itself.  Is there any way I can have the Css affect only the button and not the textbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know asp.net, but at a guess, try:

```
.gvbutton input[type="submit"] {
 width: 79px;
 height: 28px;
}
```

Comment: This was actually pretty close and led me to the right answer.  Instead of [type="submit"] I did [type=button] and it affected only the button and not the textbox so thanks for the help.